# Installing Helm chart from URL, "Error: gzip: invalid header"

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I’m trying to install a Helm chart from a Google Storage URL `(https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucket-name/php-1.5.tgz)`, as per the example `A full URL (helm install https://example.com/charts/foo-1.2.3.tgz)` [in the documentation here](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/using_helm.md#more-installation-methods), but I’m getting the error `Error: gzip: invalid header`.

Comment: Have you validated if your URL is valid gzip? You can try by: `wget -qO- URL | tar zxvf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the link format `https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucket-name/php-1.5.tgz` was only for browsers and redirected, a direct link to the same file can be achieved using the format `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/php-1.5.tgz`.

Answer (score 2):

I got this inappropriate error as well when I pointed to a yaml file instead or a chart directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this same gzip invalid header error....root cause seems to be that the requested file simply does not exist.

For this URL:
https://storage.googleapis.com/keptn-installer/keptn-0.8.1-29-g069dd.tgz

Through a browser I get this:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Details>No such object: keptn-installer/keptn-0.8.1-29-g069dd.tgz</Details>
</Error>
```

....and [this manifest-like URL](https://storage.googleapis.com/keptn-installer/) shows many versions of the above file, just not the version (keptn-0.8.1-29-g069dd.tgz) I'm looking for.

The golang code trying to retrieve this ([link](https://github.com/keptn/keptn/blob/069dd0f5c7b6f37a3737f4c0c9c7cf07a801b039/cli/pkg/helm/helm_helper.go#L57)) returns this error:
`Error: error retrieving Keptn Helm Chart at https://storage.googleapis.com/keptn-installer/keptn-0.8.1-29-g069dd.tgz: gzip: invalid header`

Just a complete swag, but sounds like the code I referenced needs better error checking.  Perhaps the code is unsuccessfully trying to unzip the real error message we're all hoping to see?